# How to do contigency table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have some dataframe like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmzxG.png).

I would like to create two items from the Cars column:
0 - if no have car
1  - for car owners, no matter how many

To the next i want to do contingency table but my code isn't work:

```
df[['Cars','Purchased Bike']]
cars1 = df.loc[(df['Cars'] >= 1, 'Cars')]=1
### contigency##
contigency5= pd.crosstab(cars1['Cars'], cars1['Purchased Bike'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Cars': [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 2],
    'Purchased Bike': ['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes']
})
pd.crosstab(1*(df['Cars'] > 0), df['Purchased Bike'])
>>>
Purchased Bike  No  Yes
Cars                   
0                1    3
1                3    3
```

Comment: Amazing ! Could you explain me why you put 1x(df . What's happend here ?

Comment: `(df['Cars'] > 0)` gives a boolean pd.Series (like [True, False...]). `1*(df['Cars'] > 0)` is a shortcut on numpy and pandas for making True -> 1 and False -> 0. So, you know the rest.